# Error 'specified method is not supported'. Get call stack

Tags: c#, wpf

My application is giving an error 'specified method is not supported' on a client pc. I do not know where the problem is coming from. He does not have Visual Studio installed so its impossible to debug.

Is there any way to get a call stack in WPF if I write some debug code in the application and give him the new exe?

Comment: The easiest may be to get the entire exception detail with `ex.ToString()`.  That shows you the call stack and any inner exception detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to `DispatcherUnhandledException` to capture the unhandled exception at application level and to log stack trace of exception.

Example of `DispatcherUnhandledException` in App.xaml.cs

```
public App() {
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        string errorMessage = string.Format("An unhandled exception occurred: {0}", e.Exception.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

In a big picture you can capture a exception at :
You can trap unhandled exceptions at different levels:

1. `AppDomain.UnhandledException` From all threads in the AppDomain.
2. `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` From a single specific UI dispatcher
   thread.
3. `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` From the main UI
   dispatcher thread in your WPF application.
4. `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` from within each AppDomain
   that uses a task scheduler for asynchronous operations. You should
   consider what level you need to trap unhandled exceptions at.

Deciding between #2 and #3 depends upon whether you're using more than one WPF thread.